# Change Button content to contain outside variable content XAML

Tags: xaml, variables, button, radio-button, richtextbox

I am trying to make a Button that has a variable for it's contents. Is there a way to do this making the content of the Button a RichTextBox or is there any better way to try this?
I can only edit the XAML code for this purpose and can not change the C# code behind.

I have my RichTextBox being a variable brought in from an outside source, and need Button contents to do the same.

```
<RichTextBox Height="30" Width="300" xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:Tecan.VisionX.TouchTools.RUP.AttachedProperties;assembly=Tecan.VisionX.TouchTools.RUP" custom:AttachedUIProperties.VariableName="XYZ" custom:AttachedUIProperties.KeyboardMode="None" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>

<RadioButton x:Name="ABC" Content="(***I want this to be an outside variable***)"  xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:Tecan.VisionX.TouchTools.RUP.AttachedProperties;assembly=Tecan.VisionX.TouchTools.RUP" custom:AttachedUIProperties.VariableName="ABC" Margin="35,175,0,0"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you create a custom user control. This control should have a rich text box and a radio button. Then you should create a usercontrol, and then use dependency property for the Content.

Comment: Do you know if I would be able to use DataBinding, to bind the RadioButton contents to the RichTextBox content?